# How to run telnet in qnx

Tags: telnet, qnx

I am trying to transfer my console application written in ncurses under the terminal connected to the com port to the virtual terminal using telnetd.
When you try to start telnetd, you get: telnetd: getpeername: Socket operation on non-socket. When connected via putty, the connection crashes. netstat shows:
[netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2NWQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

telnetd expects to be started via inetd.   See http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide/topic/tcpip_Daemons.html for information on how to set up inetd on QNX.

Comment: I did just this instruction. I run telnetd via inetd.